# Is it OK to leave one of the potentiometer pins open in this case?

Tags: potentiometer, rheostat

I want to use two potentiometers to limit current and fine tune the load of a basic photodiode circuit.

The diode specifications and the voltage values are not yet clear but I want to use two potentiometers as a variable resistor in the following way:

[image]

As you see the wiper pins (w) of the pottentiometers are left open (pin 3 is left open.)

In some schematics, I see this w pin is connected to pin 3. Is it OK in my case to leave them open?

Comment: Why does your strange circuit short the output from the wiper to ground? I say strange because, it's highly unlikely that the left pot will be of any use other than creating noise and poor measurements (should you fix the short circuit).

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for comment. The I want Rpot2 as a variable load resistor thats why. I dont wanna use it as a pot which wont change the load. I would appreciate an answer I didnt get what you mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a comments under the question: -

> *I want Rpot2 as a variable load resistor*

You need to fix your circuit this way: -

[image]

Can you see that I have moved the output to your ADC to a different place.

I also point out that Rpot1 is not needed because it doesn't really do anything. If, however, you wanted Rpot1 to control the reverse bias voltage on D1's cathode then, you'd connect pin 3 to ground but, you'd also put a 10 nF to 100 nF from wiper to ground to ensure the reverse bias voltage isn't noisy.

> *I would appreciate an answer I didnt get what you mean*

For rheostat operation, it's usually better to connect pin 3 to the wiper in the circuit above because wipers can be a little intermittent when being moved and with pin 3 connected, the maximum open-circuit impedance (when the pot is intermittent in its connection) will be 1 kΩ.

Comment: Thanks! I see the mistake now. And modified it from your answer. Is it how you say now: https://ibb.co/9VN0GsC ?

Comment: @user4444 that looks much better now.

Answer (score 4):

With pin 3 left open, during adjustment there may be moments where the pot wiper is open circuit (those these are hopefully very limited in duration).

For this kind of application it is normally better to connect the wiper to pin 3.  This means that even during adjustment, there is a well defined value in the adjustable range.

Comment: Why virtual?  It is very real...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist A turn of speech. You are of course right it may be totally open. I will edit.

Answer (score 4):

Its slightly better to connect the end of the element to the wiper.

In the case of your particular circuit, the ADC input is grounded so I don't think you'll get much in the way of signal from the ADC. Maybe it's an error, but even with changes not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

## How to demystify simple circuit tricks

> In some schematics, I see this w pin is connected to pin 3.

The OP's question took me back to my school days when as a novice electronics hobbyist I would try to figure out such circuit tricks in specific poorly explained schematics in hobbyist magazines. This connection drove me crazy with its seeming meaninglessness. That is why, I will now gladly reveal its "philosophy". I call it so with this figurative name because behind every specific thing there is some general idea that must be realized in order to understand the specific thing.

## Philosophy of extreme protection

### 1.Unprotected circuit

When we change a quantity (resistance or conductance here), it is possible to reach undesirable extreme values:

**Zero resistance (short circuit)** - the current becomes extremely high that can damage a circuit device. This situation is intuitively well understood.

A typical example is a voltage-supplied (Ohm's) circuit where trying to keep constant 10 V across the resistor, the voltage source increases the current through the resistor up to 10 A. That is why, in the schematic below, I have set some minimum (1 Ω) ammeter internal resistance to limit the current to a reasonable value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJYlvR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Infinite resistance (open circuit)** - the voltage becomes extremely high that can be dangerous. This situation is more difficult to understand intuitively.  And really, how can a circuit break be dangerous?

To understand it, let's consider a typical example - a current-supplied circuit (e.g. containing inductors). Trying to pass its 1 mA current through the resistor, the current source increases the voltage across the resistor to gigantic 1 MV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuH9om.png)</sup>

### 2.Protected circuit

To avoid these extreme situations, we can use a simple trick **representing the quantity as a sum of two components - *variable* and *constant***. Thus when the variable component becomes zero or infinity, the constant component remains and protects the circuit.

**Protecting resistor in series:** Thus, if we connect a small resistor in series to the variable one (Rtot = Rvar + Rp), it will limit the current when the variable resistance becomes zero (short circuit).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUlbC1.png)</sup>

**Protecting resistor in parallel:** Similarly, if we connect a resistor in parallel to the variable one (Gtot = Gvar + Gp), it will limit the voltage when the variable resistance is infinite or, in other words, the variable conductance is zero (open circuit).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJUBPp.png)</sup>

### 3.Unprotected variable resistor

**"Normal" circuit:** Thus, we can see two dangers in the famous 19th century implementation of a variable resistor (the so-called "rheostat").

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8rLGD.png)</sup>

**Short circuit:** The first is when its wiper reaches the initial position (zero resistance). As a result, the current would be extremely high (limited only by the ammeter's 1 Ω internal resistance).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs2OMu.png)</sup>

**Open circuit:** The second danger can be breaking due to a bad contact between the wiper and resistive material (infinite resistance). Now the voltage would be extremely high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fISDSw.png)</sup>

### 4.Protected variable resistor

**Short-circuit protection:** So to protect the circuit against a short connection, we can add as above a small Rp resistor in series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwm8lJ.png)</sup>

**Open-circuit protection:** And to protect the circuit against a wiper breaking, we can connect the unused pot terminal to the wiper so that the lower pot section is in parallel to the wiper connection.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvvDdh.png)</sup>

**Disconnected wiper:** Then, when the wiper is disconnected, the total pot resistance (between the end terminals) will remain connected in the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGqIaS.png)</sup>

### 5.More considerations

It is interesting to see what the voltage is at the unconnected terminal of the potentiometer (no load connected). It turns out that it follows the wiper voltage through the resistance of that part of the potentiometer and therefore it depends on where the wiper is connected.

When it is grounded…

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXBTel.png)</sup>

… the voltage at the free terminal is always zero.

[image: STEP 5.1]

When the wiper is connected to the side of the voltage source...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL418m.png)</sup>

… the voltage at the free terminal follows it.

[image: STEP 5.2a]

[image: STEP 5.2b]

### 6.Op-amp applications

The gain of an op-amp circuit with negative feedback can be adjusted by a variable resistor. Let's consider, as an example, an *inverting amplifier* where the feedback resistor R2 is replaced by a variable resistor (a potentiometer connected as a rheostat).

**Unprotected circuit:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flGHzr.png)</sup>

**Disconnected wiper:** The worst thing about a negative feedback circuit is to break the feedback loop (disconnected wiper). Then the op-amp saturates and its output voltage approaches the supply voltage. As a result, the next device (e.g. with TTL input) may be damaged.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpUohq.png)</sup>

**Protected circuit:** By applying the simple trick above, there will always be a closed negative feedback loop.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0dQ9t.png)</sup>

## Conclusions

Let's finally summarize all this wisdom above in conclusions:

- We can protect a variable resistor (a potentiometer connected as a rheostat) against a short circuit by connecting a protecting resistor in series.
- We can reduce the effect of wiper breaks (open circuit) on a variable resistor by connecting its unused terminal to the wiper; thus this section appears in parallel with the wiper connection.